# How to map driver id and application id of spark job

Tags: apache-spark

I am using spark rest api to submit my spark jobs.I am getting driver id as response but I want to map this driver id with corresponding application id of sparkjobs.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? How did you get the driverId back?